# Compare cell values with folder names

Tags: excel, vba

I only found questions comparing cell values with filenames.

I need to compare a column's cell values with folder names and if they match change their color to red.

```
Sub cell_value_exists_in_folder_list()

    Dim RangeOfCells As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Folder As String

    Dim TotalRow As Long

    TotalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set RangeOfCells = Range("A2:A" & TotalRow)

    For Each Cell In RangeOfCells

        Folder = "C:\" & Cell
        If Cell = Folder Then
            Cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
        Else
            Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
        
    Next Cell
    
    MsgBox "100%, please check"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the folder is exist or not. You can do that by using `DIR()` function. Try below.

```
Sub cell_value_exists_in_folder_list()

    Dim RangeOfCells As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Folder As String

    Set RangeOfCells = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each Cell In RangeOfCells
        Folder = "C:\" & Cell
        If Dir(Folder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then 'Confirm folder is exist.
            Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next Cell
    
    MsgBox "100%, please check"

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @ChristofferTrabjerg Glad to know. Please consider accepting the answer so that other visitor can know it solve your problem. Tick mark the answer to accept it.

Comment: Yes, needed to wait a few mins to be able to accept it, done now.<
Another thing that falls under this same question (I think) is if instead of coloring the cell calue red let's say I want an "X" in the cell next to it?

Comment: Then use this line `Cell.Offset(0,1)="x"`.